# What is the grammatical role of the last line of Gray's 'Elegy'?

Tags: grammaticality, syntactic-analysis, poetic-devices

The last line of Thomas Gray's poem 'Elegy Written in a Country Churchyard' is 'The bosom of his Father and his God."

> Here rests his head upon the lap of Earth
> A youth to Fortune and to Fame unknown.
> Fair Science frown'd not on his humble birth,
> And Melancholy mark'd him for her own.
>
> Large was his bounty, and his soul sincere,
> Heav'n did a recompense as largely send:
> He gave to Mis'ry all he had, a tear,
> He gain'd from Heav'n ('twas all he wish'd) a friend.
>
> No farther seek his merits to disclose,
> Or draw his frailties from their dread abode,
> (There they alike in trembling hope repose)
> The bosom of his Father and his God.

How does this line fit grammatically with the rest of the stanza? The best I can figure is that it is simply an interjection. I understand that he wants to end on a transcendental note, but it seems that perhaps he is using his poetic license to the breaking point to do so.

Comment: I'd say it reprises and restates / amplifies the *first* line - ***here***. The subject is both "here" and "in bosom of his Father and his God". But this is poetic interpretation, not something accessible through any principles of grammar and syntax.

Comment: @FumbleFingers it's a good call, as those three verses form the last section of the poem: Epitaph.

Comment: @YosefBaskin: Bosoms don't repose. They're *where* you repose! :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> The bosom of his Father and his God.

is in (somewhat ironic) apposition to "their dread abode", which is a euphemism for "death".

Answer (score 10):

tl;dr: Greybeard’s apposition analysis is correct.

But here, perhaps, is everything you could have hoped for . . .

[*Gray’s Elegy, with Literary and Grammatical Explanations and Comments, and Suggestions as to how it Should be Taught*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Gray_s_Elegy/f1sVAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0) (Reginald Heber Holbrook, 1886)

[image: cover of Gray’s Elegy]

[Read it for free at Google Books.](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Gray_s_Elegy/f1sVAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1)

Here’s the analysis (page 43):

> ***32.*** **No farther seek his merits to disclose,
>  Or draw his frailties from their dread abode,
>  (There they alike in trembling
> hope repose,)
>  The bosom of his Father and his God.**
>
> INTRODUCTORY. —The highest test of any effort is its *finale*. Of the
> many masterly strokes of this poem, this stanza, as a culminating,
> finishing touch, is perhaps the most matchless.
>
> How deftly does he relieve himself of his theme, in the first two
> lines; and with what dignified composure does he, in the last two,
> lead us into and leave us in the solemn presence of a “Father and a
> God.”
>
> ***Merits:*** —Object of “disclose.”
>
> ***To disclose:*** —Object of “seek.”
>
> ***Dread:*** —Venerable in the highest degree, inspiring awe; as, *dread sovereign*. The difference between *dread* and *fear* is distinctly
> implied in the familiar lines:
>  <sub>“Wherein doth sit the dread
> and fear of kings.”</sub>
>
> ***Abode:*** —The “dread abode” is the “bosom of his Father and his God.”
>
> ***There:*** —That is, in their dread abode.
>
> ***They:*** —That is, his “merits” and “frailties.”
>
> ***Bosom:*** —Objective, in apposition with “abode.”

PS: In the hymnals, the *dread abode* is not Death but that awe-inspiring home: Eternity (see e.g. [*A Selection of Psalms and Hymns*](https://books.google.com/books?id=3r5VAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA203&lpg=PA203&dq=%22eternity+the+dread+abode%22+%22hymn%22&source=bl&ots=rjaG7WdGEh&sig=ACfU3U1mGdQoJWRhyLPIj3OLKhziG1D1Xw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiduJWf_5mCAxU7ATQIHT_5BdgQ6AF6BAgIEAM#v=onepage&q=%22eternity%20the%20dread%20abode%22%20%22hymn%22&f=false)).

Answer (score 5):

Omitting the parenthesized penultimate line:

> No farther seek his merits to disclose,
> Or draw his frailties from their dread abode,
> The bosom of his Father and his God.

Seems to clarify the role of the last line, which qualifies the 'dread abode' of his frailties.

Paraphrasing that last verse:

> Don't ask any more about his strengths and weaknesses; I've said enough, so let him lie in peace.